# HttpWebRequest Metrics in .NET Similar to Firebug or Pingdom Tools

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, metrics

I'm looking for a way to measure each step of a (HTTP) web request in .NET similar to Firebug's network waterfall timeline or Pingdom.com's full page test.

Both share a lowest common denominator of showing time spans required for each request to:

- Lookup DNS
- Connect
- Send the request
- Wait for response
- Receive response

Obviously I can use a timer to measure the web requests GetResponse() and GetResponseStream() methods, but I'm looking for a way to be as granular as possible with as many measurements as possible.

**What's the best way in .NET to measure each stage of the request life cycle?**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a way to accomplish this from inside the application that would be posting the `HTTPWebRequest` or from a separate application? Either way you may be able to leverage SharpPcap to monitor the network traffic.

Comment: M.Babcock, Yes, I'm looking for a way to do this inside the application that's initiating the web request.  I'll take a look at SharpPcap - as long as it's Azure friendly that may work.

Comment: James, Glimpse is tied to the .NET pipeline.  I'm looking at capturing stats from a web request I initiate in code, not from the web server handling the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at ETW tracing to do this. AFAIK ETW tracing output a ton of information from many .NET APIs. At least I see it all the time when I use reflector to browse the .NET framework.

If ETW cannot do this I am pretty sure you can hook many relevant points in the pipeline:

- Lookup DNS: Do the lookup yourself and measure the timing. The HttpWebRequest's internal lookup will now be served from cache and execute in 0ms.
- Connect: This happend when you call GetRequestStream()
- Send the request: This happens when you call GetRequestStream().Dispose()
- Wait for response: This happens when you call GetResponseStream()
- Receive response: This happens when GetResponseStream().Read() returns 0.